# EA addin - not visible on citrix

Tags: add-in, enterprise-architect

I created an addin in C#. I installed/register this addin (MyAddin.dll) on the server and is visible and working, but when i tried on citrix the addin is not visible, do you know why?  Multiple users log-in on citrix.

On the server I used scripts:

RegisterAddin.reg

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Sparx Systems\EAAddins\MyAddin]
@="MyAddin.MyAddin"

Reg.bat

```
%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regasm %~dp0\MyAddin.dll /codebase
```

Comment: You need to wait for Geert to come out of holidays.

Comment: solved the problem after I added a register key in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE

Comment: You should post that as answer to yourself - and set the tick mark next day or so.